# "Left behind after class?" Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence correct?

"*I left my book behind after class*."

What I want to say is that my character left their book behind after class, so they went back to get it. I know I could say "*I left my book behind in the classroom*" instead, but I want to put emphasis on the timeframe instead of the location (which is the garden, in this case), if that makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it's a little "weird", since presumably what you've written equates to *I left it behind **when I left** class* - by the time you'd *actually* left class, the book would *already* have been left behind.

Comment: You're right!  That sounds much better. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds fine to me. Personally, I actually prefer it to the alternatives suggested.